# Cant use dot or bracket notation to access keys or data in json/javascript object saved to state after fetch

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch, native

I'm currently learning react-native after some time on react and have come across a weird occurrence I don't understand.

I am fetching a JSON file from an API and saving it in my state. Elsewhere in the file when I try to access values with dot and bracket notation it breaks my code saying 'undefined is not an object' and the value of this constant is indeed undefined. But the strange part is if I then use setState inside my fetch and dot/bracket notation to get a specific value it works fine. But I want to have this functionality else whereas I will be mapping through the data a lot.

I read I might need to use `JSON.parse` but could work out where to place this in my fetch and it returned an error inside a console.log.

JSON.stringify works but then I just have a huge string so have lost the power of an object.

Dot and bracket notation tried it all as I say works inside fetch perfectly but when calling the state

First setting the state into a const then passing this into the console.log, no difference.

```
fetchWeather(lat = 15, lon = 85) {
    fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&APPID&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=metric`,
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          forecast: json.list,
          temp: json.list[0].main.temp // WORKS! returns temp eg 25.34
          isLoading: false,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

```
console.log(this.state.forecast[0]); //works I get the first index of an array of objects but has and added key Object {}
console.log(this.state.forecast[0].main.temp); //undefined
console.log(this.state.forecast[0]['main']['temp']); //undefined
```

I see this Object {} showing up in the console but maybe this isn't anything to worry about?

**eg.**

```
"main": Object {
    "grnd_level": 1008.34,
    "humidity": 54,
    "pressure": 1013.04,
    "sea_level": 1013.04,
    "temp": 28.1,
    "temp_kf": 4.74,
    "temp_max": 28.1,
    "temp_min": 23.36,
},
```

**should be,**

```
"main": {
    "grnd_level": 1008.34,
    "humidity": 54,
    "pressure": 1013.04,
    "sea_level": 1013.04,
    "temp": 28.1,
    "temp_kf": 4.74,
    "temp_max": 28.1,
    "temp_min": 23.36,
  },
```

I expect from `console.log(this.state.forecast[0].main.temp)` return `23.45` and
`console.log(this.state.forecast[0]['main'])` `return`

```
"grnd_level": 1008.34,
"humidity": 54,
"pressure": 1013.04,
"sea_level": 1013.04,
"temp": 28.1,
"temp_kf": 4.74,
"temp_max": 28.1,
"temp_min": 23.36,
```

https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Wils0nC00k/110b906afa06dfbf2ebee36fbfe40e9a

Comment: From your question and Gist it is not really clear to me where you're trying to access your state and experience the error - however, please be aware that `setState` *enqueues* changes. Do not attempt to access these fields immediately after calling `setState`. `setState` accepts a callback as a second argument that you can use.

Comment: It's just bizarre to store an object in my state as forecast, then when I place a console.log in my render method to not be able to access keys & values with dot or bracket notation. It's like it isn't an object? How would you access "temp" from the object?

Comment: Please note that this condition always evaluates to `true` and the `console.log` will be attempted even before the state is properly filled: `if (this.state.forecast !== {}) {` - if it's breaking in this `console.log` then this is the reason.

Comment: I've added this as an answer, please accept if my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this part in your Gist is causing the error:

```
if (this.state.forecast !== {}) {
  console.log(this.state.forecast[0].main);
}
```

You're initializing your `state.forecast` with an empty object `{}` and try to check for that.

Judging from the data structure perspective, this is a bit misleading, because the actual content will be an array.

More importantly, though, the two variables are compared by identity and the right operand is an empty object newly created on the stack every time `render` is called and can never be equal to whatever is in `forecast`. Thus, the condition always evaluates to `true` which leads to an attempt to access data which is not yet present at the first render.

As you're only waiting for `forecast` to be filled through the `fetch` call, and the content of `forecast` is known, it should be sufficient to initialize the `state` with `forecast: null` (or not at all) and then check if `forecast` is set at all (not `false`, not `null`, not `undefined`, not 0, not `''`,...):

```
if (this.state.forecast) {
  console.log(this.state.forecast[0].main);
}
```

Or a bit more strict:

```
if (typeof this.state.forecast === 'object') { // typeof array is also 'object'
  console.log(this.state.forecast[0].main);
}
```

Comment: It must be something about lifecycles or scope as it works inside the set state but not elsewhere in the App I'm assuming?

Comment: The "Object: {" is just your browser's way to dump the variable - Firefox does it like that, Chrome not.

Comment: Which line in your App.js Gist fails?

Comment: My error message says - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.forecast[0].main')

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that you initialize the state with an empty object `{}` - remove that, initialize as `null` or not at all, and it will work. I will amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: It breaks with the console.log Line 66, also if it tries to display the string value as text inside <Text></Text> it breaks also so isn't specific to me using a console.log

Comment: THAT'S IT! THANK YOU SO MUCH! Now you have told me that makes sense why it would break, will use null from now on. So much help, thanks again. Will accept answer now